# bxslider disappear in safari

Tags: jquery, safari, bxslider

Im using last bxslider [link here](http://bxslider.com) and i found some bug using safari browser on OSX. OS: El Capitan 10.11. Safari 9.0

When i refresh site like CMD+R or in Windows F5 its works fine.
But when i click logo which is home page link and goes to same location bxslider disappear.

1. Maybe you know where is the problem.
2. Maybe you tell me that i should use `bxslider.reloadSlider` but i don't know how because its works fine only on click
3. Maybe you have some other free responsive slider.

Here is website where i put bxslider - [website with bxslider](http://promyk.advanced.iq.pl/)

Answer (score 1):

I have that problem and i solve it by remove 'mode: "fade",' from the option of bxslider.

ElCapitain dont like the